# Form Validation not happening for Django model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I have created the following model form and I want to apply validation on it but it is not working. Can anyone please tell me what mistake I am making?

```
"""class used for booking a time slot."""
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_in_time', 'check_out_time',
                    'person', 'no_of_rooms']

    """Function to check if username and password match or not."""
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        normal_book_date = cleaned_data.get("check_in_date")
        normal_check_in = cleaned_data.get("check_in_time")

        if (normal_book_date < now.date() or
            (normal_book_date == now.date() and
            normal_check_in < now.time())):

            #self._errors['check_in_date'] = self.error_class([
            #    'You can only book for future.])
            raise ValidationError(
                "You can only book for future."
            )
        return cleaned_data
```

Edit:
Here is the template that I am rendering. I want to show the error in the template itself. Like how real forms work and show errror.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Booking</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'hotel/css/base.css' %}">
    <style>
      *{
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
      }

  </style>
  </head>
    <body id="body-color">
    <div class="container2" id="boxx">
      <h2 class="w3-center">Room Slot Booking</h2><br/>
      <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <input type="submit" class= "submit submit-right" value="Search Availability" />
      </form>
      <br/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the views.py file

```
"""Function to return the available categories."""
@login_required(login_url="/hotel/signin/")
def booking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['normal_book_date'] = request.POST['check_in_date']
            normal_book_date = convert_to_date(request.session['normal_book_date'])
            request.session['normal_check_in'] = request.POST['check_in_time']
            normal_check_in = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_in'])
            request.session['normal_check_out'] = request.POST['check_out_time']
            # now is the date and time on which the user is booking.
            if (normal_book_date > now.date() or
                (normal_book_date == now.date() and
                normal_check_in >= now.time())):
                request.session['normal_person'] = int(request.POST['person'])
                request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'] = int(
                    request.POST['no_of_rooms']
                    )
                normal_check_out = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_out'])
                response = list()
                response = search_availability(True,
                                               normal_book_date,
                                               normal_check_in,
                                               normal_check_out,
                                               request.session['normal_person'],
                                               request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'])
                if response:
                    context = {
                        'categories': response,
                        'username': request.session['normal_username']
                        }
                    return render(request, 'categories.html', context)
                return HttpResponse("Not Available")
            else:
                context = {
                    'form': BookingForm(),
                    'username': request.session['normal_username']
                    }
                return render(request, 'book.html', context)
        else:
            context = {
                'form': BookingForm(),
                'username': request.session['normal_username']
                }
            return render(request, 'book.html', context)
    context = {
        'form': BookingForm(),
        'username': request.session['normal_username']
        }
    return render(request, 'book.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `is_valid()` instead of the clean.. That's where I've found success

```py
"""class used for booking a time slot."""
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['check_in_date', 'check_in_time', 'check_out_time',
                    'person', 'no_of_rooms']

    """Function to check if username and password match or not."""
    def is_valid(self):
        valid = super(BookingForm, self).is_valid()
        # ^ valid is a Boolean

        # Note: added self to cleaned_data.get()
        normal_book_date = self.cleaned_data.get("check_in_date")
        normal_check_in = self.cleaned_data.get("check_in_time")

        if (normal_book_date < now.date() or
            (normal_book_date == now.date() and
            normal_check_in < now.time())):

            valid = False

            # Not sure if this works, or is needed (the "raise" part mostly)
            #   if it doesn't work just add the error to the field instead (see below)
            raise ValidationError(
                "You can only book for future."
            )

            # You could also add the error msg per field & it will render it
            #   - extra tidbit
            self.add_error('normal_book_date', 'You can only book for future.')

        return valid
```

That is_valid is called when you do `form.is_valid()` in the view, so make sure you're doing that too

---

#### Edit

Here's how you would pass the failed form to the render. You just pass that `form` variable instead of init a new `BookingForm()`
Not only will it show the Errors, but it will keep the fields filled with whatever you submitted (instead of clearing the entire form)

###### view.py

```py
"""Function to return the available categories."""
@login_required(login_url="/hotel/signin/")
def booking(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BookingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['normal_book_date'] = request.POST['check_in_date']
            normal_book_date = convert_to_date(request.session['normal_book_date'])
            request.session['normal_check_in'] = request.POST['check_in_time']
            normal_check_in = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_in'])
            request.session['normal_check_out'] = request.POST['check_out_time']

            # This should be in the form.is_valid() & removes an else
            #
            # now is the date and time on which the user is booking.
            # if (normal_book_date > now.date() or
            #    (normal_book_date == now.date() and
            #    normal_check_in >= now.time())):

            request.session['normal_person'] = int(request.POST['person'])
            request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'] = int(
                request.POST['no_of_rooms']
                )
            normal_check_out = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_out'])
            response = list()
            response = search_availability(True,
                                           normal_book_date,
                                           normal_check_in,
                                           normal_check_out,
                                           request.session['normal_person'],
                                           request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'])
            if response:
                # Success!
                context = {
                    'categories': response,
                    'username': request.session['normal_username']
                    }
                return render(request, 'categories.html', context)
            # no availability
            return HttpResponse("Not Available")

        else:
            context = {
                'form': form, # <- pass the failed form to the render
                'username': request.session['normal_username']
                }
            return render(request, 'book.html', context)
    context = {
        'form': BookingForm(),
        'username': request.session['normal_username']
        }
    return render(request, 'book.html', context)
```

To really clean it up and remove some extra `else` you could only use a **single** form variable

###### view.py (condensed)

```py
"""Function to return the available categories."""
@login_required(login_url="/hotel/signin/")
def booking(request):
    # Init the form  - This will either:
    #   a) init a new form (if no POST)
    #   b) fill form with POST data
    form = BookingForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['normal_book_date'] = request.POST['check_in_date']
            normal_book_date = convert_to_date(request.session['normal_book_date'])
            request.session['normal_check_in'] = request.POST['check_in_time']
            normal_check_in = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_in'])
            request.session['normal_check_out'] = request.POST['check_out_time']

            request.session['normal_person'] = int(request.POST['person'])
            request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'] = int(
                request.POST['no_of_rooms']
                )
            normal_check_out = convert_to_time(request.session['normal_check_out'])
            response = list()
            response = search_availability(True,
                                           normal_book_date,
                                           normal_check_in,
                                           normal_check_out,
                                           request.session['normal_person'],
                                           request.session['normal_no_of_rooms_required'])
            if response:
                # Success!
                context = {
                    'categories': response,
                    'username': request.session['normal_username']
                    }
                return render(request, 'categories.html', context)
            # no availability
            return HttpResponse("Not Available")

        # Implied else, form failed is_valid and `form` now has the .errors attribute
        #   (will render the page with it)

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'username': request.session['normal_username']
        }
    return render(request, 'book.html', context)
```

Comment: It is not working. The ValidationError() is not displaying error in the form as I wanted and add_error() is not working.

Comment: but the validation **is** working, right?- like it's not letting you save. per the error messages: Edit your original question to include the template with the form you're working with.. depending on how you are rendering it you might just be missing the error template tag

Comment: As you requested I have added the template.

Comment: mmm, you're template is correct. Could you also add your **view**?- maybe you're not passing the failed form to the render

Comment: Maybe you are right but I don't know how to "pass the failed form to the render". Can you help?

Comment: that's what it was, you were always rendering the page with a new form instead of the validated one. **Note:** My edit assumes you are using my original `is_valid()` block with the `self.add_error` instead of the `raise` - I also chopped out an else because it was confusing